# How to open BottomSheetDialogFragment fully expanded in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I am able to open my BottomSheetDialogFragment with

```
val bottomSheet = BottomSheetFragment()
bottomSheet.show(fragmentManager!!, "BottomSheet")
```

but it only opens to show half of its content - I would like it to expand on opening to the full height of the screen without having to drag it up.

I have looked around and it seems one way is to set the BottomSheetBehavior state to STATE_EXPANDED, but I have not been able to find a solution on how to do this in Kotlin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set the `BottomSheetBehavior` state by placing this inside 
`onViewCreated` of your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
    val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
    val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
    val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```

You may also want to set the peek height to the height of your dialog to prevent the dialog getting stuck half way when attempting to dismiss it.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = bottomSheet.height
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Just had to change the findViewbyId argument to com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet as I'm using Androidx

Comment: Works for me, just had to give the dialog `.xml` layout file some minimum height, as I don't have much content.

Comment: Worked like a charm, likewise @SQLol had to change it from "R.id.design_bottom_sheet" to "com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet" thanks

Comment: not able to show bottom sheet.             bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager!!, "BottomSheet")
showing error in this line

Comment: The issue with setting `bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = bottomSheet.height` is that when you swipe down to dismiss, the dialog does not actually dismiss and you are left with a greyed overlap on the screen.

Comment: In order to avoid having a greyed overlap, instead use `bottomSheetBehavior.skipCollapsed = true`.

Comment: Please update the answer. @JeanTadebois's suggestion of setting BottomSheetBehavior.skipCollapsed  to true to prevent the dialog from being stuck half way is the better/cleaner choice.